# ¿Como desactivar el click de un botón con Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

Tengo un botón que tengo desactivado mientras no tengo los datos del formulario guardado.
Esto lo hago con Thymeleaf:

```
  <a class="btn btn-block-xs btn-info m-b-5" th:href="(@{/miruta/})" th:disabled="${id} == null">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-small"></span>
    <span th:text="#{nombre.boton}"></span>
</a>
```

Y me aparece el botón desactivado pero me permite hacer click en el igualmente.
Alguna solución para hacerlo por thymeleaf sin necesidad de usar javascript o jquery.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

th:disabled no funciona en mi caso porque tengo un enlace , si fuera un  funcionaria correctamente.
La solución para desactivar el click de un botón es haciendo un condición para el th:href

Mi código queda de la siguiente manera

```
<a class="btn btn-block-xs btn-info m-b-5" th:href="${id} != null ? (@{/miruta/}) : '#'" th:disabled="${id} == null">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-small"></span>
    <span th:text="#{nombre.boton}"></span>
</a>
```